# Report of all deployments over 1 week and 1 month

Tags: azure, powershell, graph, resources, report

I'm trying to get a report of everything that have been deployed in the last week and month using Azure Resource Graph, activity log, change history or Powershell but can't find any good way to do it.

I have tried using the Search-AzGraph command unsuccessfully and can't find any good way with any of the other things listed.

I'm trying to get a report with resource type, name, date, resource group, region and user for the last week and month.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below command to find the deployment history with resource manager:

```
Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleGroup
```

More information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations#powershell